# npm ERR! missing script: clean;

Tags: nodejs, script, npm, test

Estoy usando el paquete coverage de npm que me dice que partes del código cubren mis tests.
Pero al lanzar los tests poniendo `npm run coverage`, me salta el siguiente error:

> npm ERR! missing script: clean;

He mirado en el package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --exit",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=16384 server/server.js",
    "startdev": "nodemon  --ignore zdarwins/",
    "clean": "rm -rf coverage",
    "coverage": "npm run clean; nyc npm test; rm -rf .nyc_output"
  },
```

Y como se puede ver, si está el script de "clean", así que no entiendo que está fallando.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --exit",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=16384 server/server.js",
    "startdev": "nodemon  --ignore zdarwins/",
    "clean": "rm -rf coverage",
    "coverage": "npm run clean; nyc npm test; rm -rf .nyc_output"
  },
```

Según he estado investigando, ese error suele ocurrirle a la gente con el "start" cuando no tienen un script especificado ahí.

Para que funcione, seguramente debas añadir un script en "clean". Tipo así:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run eslint && npm run coverage",
  "coverage": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=test istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- test/ --recursive --exit",
  "eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.json --fix",
  "start": "node src/",
  "clean": "shx rm -rf test/data/",
  "mocha": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=test mocha test/ --recursive --exit"
},
```

Código sacado de https://gist.github.com/daffl/8d34acc881040a800120d69c55c26c11

Answer (score 0):

Me he dado cuenta de una cosa:
Mis compañeros usan mac (unix) y yo windows.
Dentro de scripts, en el package.json he añadido un script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive --exit",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=16384 server/server.js",
    "startdev": "nodemon  --ignore zdarwins/",
    "clean": "rm -rf coverage",
    "coverage": "npm run clean; nyc npm test; rm -rf .nyc_output",
    "coveragew": "npm run clean && nyc npm test && rm -rf .nyc_output"
  }
```

`coveragew` hace lo mismo que coverage pero escrito en notación para windows, o al menos aunque no me valga para powershell, me vale para bash.

Otra cosa que he hecho ha sido instalar globalmente el paquete nyc.

Con estas cosas me funciona.